# A topological groupoid structure on a pair $(X,A)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, groupoids

Assume that $X$   is a compact  Hausdorff  space and $A\subset X$  is  a  retract of $X$.

> Is there a topological  groupoid structure on the topological  pair $(X,A)$ where,  in the corresponding small category,  $X$ and $A$ plays the role of morphisms and objects, respectively.

**Edit  1:** Is there  a  theory which investigate such type of problems for  $A$ not necessarily a single point

In  particular, is there  a non single retract  $A$ of  $X=S^{3}$ or $X=S^{7}$ such that $(X,A)$ does not admit a topological  groupoid  structure.

In this  question we  do  not require that the retracting  map has any relation to the  source and range maps

**Edit 2:** As another particular case, is there a groupid structure on $(G,G^{0})$ where $G=Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $G^{0}=O(n)$? That is: are there range, source and  composition maps which are  continuous which makes $(G,G^{0})$  a  groupoid.

Comment: For $A$ a point you are asking whether there is a topological group structure on any compact Hausdorff space, with given point as a unit. Obviously not.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  thank you. What  about if we add "Non singleton A"?

Comment: and X is  connected

Comment: These sorts of dodges accomplish nothing: in any groupoid, there is a group $\hom(x, x)$ for each object $x$, imposing a heavy homogeneity condition which need not be satisfied in such generality. More importantly, if I am a researcher on this, the first question I ask is: what would the domain and codomain functions $X \to A$ be in terms of the data? I am supposing we are given a retraction $r: X \to A$ of the inclusion $i: A \hookrightarrow X$, but I can't seem to cook up a second function (unless the domain and codomain functions are actually the same). Then what would composition be??

Comment: @ToddTrimble  According to the last statment of your comment  I would  like to compare  the  situation with the  topological group case: We have  an space X then we ask is there a topological group structure on X. In this question we  do not  confirm any operation. No in the topological groupoid setting  we  have  a pair  we ask about a topological groupoid structure. So in our question we do not impose any r or  s  maps: We ask are there range  source and  composition map making the pair into a groupoid. I think I removed the misunderstanding, yes?

Comment: There's no misunderstanding, that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Note: This answer had been sent to Ali in private email (the question had been closed while I was composing it). Now that the question has been reopened, the answer may be given here. (This has been edited, but the original letter is revision 1.)

---

The answer to the question about $S^n$ and their hemispheres $H$ is yes, in a fairly easy way.

The inclusion $i: H \hookrightarrow S^n$ of the northern hemisphere has a retract $r: S^n \to H$ which linearly reflects points on the southern hemisphere across the equatorial hyperplane. Taking $C_1 = S^n$ and $C_0 = H$, and the domain and codomain maps $\partial_0, \partial_1: C_1 \rightrightarrows C_0$ both to be $r$, we may then define the object-to-identity map $u: C_0 \to C_1$ to be $i$, and we get a reflexive graph. Now we define composition to make this to a groupoid. the object $C_2 = C_1 \times_{C_0} C_1$ of composable pairs is just the kernel pair, i.e., the subspace of $C_1 \times C_1$ given by $\{(x, y): r(x) = r(y)\}$. Let $H'$ be the southern hemisphere and let $s: S^n \rightleftarrows H': j$ be the analogous retraction pair for the southern hemisphere, and define $m: C_2 \to C_1$ by $m(x, y) \mapsto i r(x)$ if $x = y$ and $(x, y) \mapsto j s(x)$ if $x \neq y$. It is not hard to check that this defines a continuous map.

The picture is that if you forget the topological structure and look at the underlying discrete groupoid, then there are no morphisms $a \to b$ if $a \neq b$, and the groupoid is a coproduct of groups $\bigsqcup_{a \in H} \hom(a, a)$ where $\hom(a, a)$ is the trivial group if $a$ lies on the equator, and $\hom(a, a)$ is the group $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ if $a$ is off the equator. As a *groupoid* this is not connected (since there are no morphisms $a \to b$ between distinct $a, b$), although the total space $C_1$ is a connected space.

Comment: +1  for your interesting answer. The retracting map is  not important in our  question. So we  do not  require that the source and range maps relate to the initial retracting map. We assume that A is retract since this is a necessary  condition.

Comment: I think, even in the law dimensional case  Gl(2,R) and  O(2), perhaps  the problem is interesting.

Comment: Ali, I understand. I've removed editorial comments.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer.Regarding the homogenous property of Hom (x,x), when we apply your very interesting point to $Gl(n,

Comment: $Gl(n, \mathbb{R}$ and its retract $O(n)$, we realize that $Hom(I,I)$ is the space of invertible upper triangle matrices with poisitive digonal; a homogenous space.

Comment: Note that we apply your Idea if r=s= retracting map. Here retracting map is the classical Grahm Schmidt map.

Comment: So I think that the question in the post is very broad, so I decide to ask a new question  just for general linear group and orthonormal group.But your essential point about homogenous property was very helpful

Comment: What about homogenous property if we replace I by another invertible matrix?

Comment: Nice. I wonder if this also has a *smooth* (Lie) groupoid structure. Looks like there is some sort of singularity along the equator but I am not sure I understand what that means.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  There is  a smooth groupoid structure as it is written in the answer to the following question:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247935/the-pair-gln-mathbbr-on-as-a-groupoid?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  You are  well come!