# The pair $(Gl(n,\mathbb{R}), O(n) )$ as a groupoid

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, groupoids

"Is there a topological groupoid structure on the pair $(Gl(n,\mathbb{R}), O(n))$, with their standard topologies?"

This is already asked here but this linked question is a very general question, so we consider its special case about general linear group, as an independent question.

[A topological groupoid structure on a pair $(X,A)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247587/a-topological-groupoid-structure-on-a-pair-x-a)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an easy differentiable groupoid structure: Use the Iwasawa decomposition
$G=KAN= K\times A\times N$. In the case of the question this is the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization proceedure for the rows and remembering the coefficients as an upper triangular matrix with positive entries on the main diagonal: $GL(n)\ni g = k.a.n\in O(n)\times \mathbb R_{>0}^n\times N$ where $N$ are upper triangular matrices with 1 on the main diagonal. We take $k.a.n \mapsto k$ as source and target map, and the groupoid structure is then $(k.a_1.n_1,k.a_2.n_2)\mapsto k.a_1.n_1.a_2.n_2$.

Comment: Prof.  Michor Thank you for your  attention to my question and your very interesting answer.